# Shell Script Start a Server and return

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that starts a server. I actually ssh into my server and run the shell script. As soon as it starts, it logs everything to the console and the console does not return. The problem starts when I close my Machine, the ssh connection is disconnected and the server that I started is shutdown. I guess I need to start the server and return from the shell. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx1G -Dhttp.port=8080 -Dconfig.file=MyProject/conf/application.conf -cp ".:MyProject/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer .
exit 0
```

Any suggestions on how to return after calling this shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ssh to the server Just backgrounding your script (./myscript &) will not daemonize it. You must disconnect stdin, stdout, and stderr, and make it ignore the hangup signal (SIGHUP).

nohup ./myscript 0<&- &>/dev/null &

will do the job. Or, to capture all output:

nohup ./myscript 0<&- &> my.admin.log.file &

Answer (score 1):

To avoid script termination on ssh session close use `nohup` (No hangup) with output redirection to a log file:

```
nohup bash /path/to/startScript.sh > script.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Seems not to work. As soon as I start the server, it gives me a PID stored in a file at the same location where the start.sh is located. But when I tried using your command above, it did not run the server at all. I can see that it printed something probably the PID, but the server was not started.

Comment: Just run: `nohup ./start.sh &` and then check `nohup.out` file for any possible errors.

Comment: I think I messed it somehow. I'm now not able to stop it anymore. Where can I find the process id so that I can kill it?

Comment: You can do `pgrep -fl bash` to get process of running bash processes. OR use `ps -fu`

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it looks good now. I guess the reason was because of lack of permissions, it was not able to start the server using the nohup command. Now it looks all ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stdout and stderr to files, background and disown the process (or nohup it) and then exit the script.

However, the correct way to do this is to use some kind of process manager daemon like upstart.